# How to emulate tagged union in a database?

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys

What is the best way to emulate [Tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) in databases?
I'm talking about something like this:

```
create table t1 {
  vehicle_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES car(id) OR motor(id) -- not valid
  ...
}
```

where vehicle_id would be id in car table OR motor table, and it would know which.

(assume that motor and car tables have nothing in common0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some people use a design called Polymorphic Associations to do this, allowing `vehicle_id` to contain a value that exists either in `car` or `motor` tables.  Then add a `vehicle_type` that names the table which the given row in `t1` references.

The trouble is that you can't declare a real SQL foreign key constraint if you do this.  There's no support in SQL for a foreign key that has multiple reference targets.  There are other problems, too, but the lack of referential integrity is already a deal-breaker.

A better design is to borrow a concept from OO design of a *common supertype* of both `car` and `motor`:

```
CREATE TABLE Identifiable (
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then make `t1` reference this super-type table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  vehicle_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES identifiable(id)
  ...
);
```

And also make the sub-types reference their parent supertype.  Note that the primary key of the sub-types is *not* auto-incrementing.  The parent supertype takes care of allocating a new id value, and the children only reference that value.

```
CREATE TABLE car (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES identifiable(id)
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE motor (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES identifiable(id)
  ...
);
```

Now you can have true referential integrity, but also support multiple subtype tables with their own attributes.

---

The answer by @Quassnoi also shows a method to enforce *disjoint subtypes*.  That is, you want to prevent both `car` and `motor` from referencing the same row in their parent supertype table.  When I do this, I use a single-column primary key for `Identifiable.id` but also declare a `UNIQUE` key over `Identifiable.(id, type)`.  The foreign keys in `car` and `motor` can reference the two-column unique key instead of the primary key.

Comment: The surrogate key for `identifiable` is only good when there are attributes in `identifiable` that the query needs to select. If `identifiable` only serves to enforce the constraints, using a composite key will allow to get rid of it in the queries competely.

Comment: I've come up with & used the 'common supertype' approach myself, and used it succesfully in major system migration/redevelopment projects. (NZ Government, SPOT25 for MoE)

Answer (score 6):

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle (type INT NOT NULL, id INT NOT NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY (type, id)
)

CREATE TABLE car (type INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
             CHECK(type = 1),
             FOREIGN KEY (type, id) REFERENCES vehicle
)

CREATE TABLE motorcycle (type INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 2, id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
             CHECK(type = 2),
             FOREIGN KEY (type, id) REFERENCES vehicle
)

CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ...
  vehicle_type INT NOT NULL,
  vehicle_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_type, vehicle_id) REFERENCES vehicle
  ...
)
```

Comment: It'd make life easier if you defined `VEHICLE.VEHICLE_ID` as the primary key so you don't have to reference a composite key, and have type & id columns using a unique constraint.

Comment: `@OMG Ponies:` With this layout, you don't need to reference `vehicle` at all. You can just join with `cars` or `motorcycles`, depending on the `type`. `vehicle` here serves only to police the relationships.

Comment: With this method, is there some way to guarantee that there won't be "orphan" vehicles that don't have a corresponding row in `car` or `motorcycle`?

Answer (score 4):

I think the least-boilerplate solution is to use `constraint` and `check`.

For example, consider this ADT in Haskell:

```hs
data Shape = Circle {radius::Float} | Rectangle {width::Float, height::Float}
```

The equivalent in MySQL/MariaDB would be (tested on 10.5.11-MariaDB):

```sql
CREATE TABLE shape (        
  type ENUM('circle', 'rectangle') NOT NULL,
  radius FLOAT,             
  width FLOAT,              
  height FLOAT,             
  CONSTRAINT constraint_circle CHECK 
    (type <> 'circle' OR radius IS NOT NULL),
  CONSTRAINT constraint_rectangle CHECK 
    (type <> 'rectangle' OR (width IS NOT NULL AND height IS NOT NULL))
);                                      
                                        
INSERT INTO shape(type, radius, width, height)
  VALUES ('circle', 1, NULL, NULL); -- ok
                                                                                                                    
INSERT INTO shape(type, radius, width, height)
  VALUES ('circle', NULL, 1, NULL); -- error, constraint_circle violated
```

Note that the above uses `type <> x OR y` instead of `type = x AND y`. This is because the latter essentially means that all rows must have `type` of `x`, which defeats the purpose of tagged union.

Also, note that the solution above only check for required columns, but does not check for extraneous columns.

For example, you can insert a `rectangle` which has defined `radius`.

This can be easily mitigated by adding another condition for `constraint_rectangle`, namely `radius is null`.

However, I will not recommend doing so as it makes adding new `type` tedious.

For example, to add a new `type` `triangle` with one new column `base`, not only we will need to add a new constraint, but we also need to modify the existing constraints to ensure that their `base` is null.

Comment: FWIW: Saying `type <> x OR y` is actually equivalent to implication: `type = x => y`. Another equivalent (arguably easier to digest) expression would be `NOT (type = x AND NOT y)`. I.e. it is **not** allowed to **be** a circle **and not** to have a radius. Your version is this transformed to a more compact form using De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could model such a reference by using [table inheritance in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-inherit.html).

If you really need to know where a row comes from in a Query, you could use a simple UNION ALL statment like (this possibility has nothing to do with table inheritance):

```
SELECT car.*, 'car' table_name
UNION ALL
SELECT motor.*, 'motor' table_name
```